# I am using vmax lib to show Ads and facing some problems

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

I can't able to import below packages:

```
import com.vmax.android.ads.api.VmaxAdSettings;
import com.vmax.android.ads.mediation.partners.VMAXVideoPlayer;
```

and due to that reason I get below errors:

```
Error:(50, 55) error: <anonymous com.ads.AboutActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onAdMediaEnd(boolean,long) in VmaxAdListener
Error:(61, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(66, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(71, 19) error: cannot find symbol method loadAd()
```

Please help me, If you have any solution for this or any example which can help me.

[VMAX SDK for Android – Alternative method](https://www.vmax.com/2017/03/24/20170324vmax-sdk-android-alternative-method),
[AdMob Integration using Android SDK](https://www.vmax.com/2016/04/14/admob-integration-using-android-sdk).

Comment: I found one solution for this check link.

https://www.vmax.com/2017/06/15/upgrade-guide-for-vmax-android-sdk-3-7-0